# How do I get a list of and perform actions on "Chrome devices for meetings" from the GSuite Admin Directory API?

Tags: google-admin-sdk

I've found the API for managing Chrome Devices (https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/manage-chrome-devices) but its list operation does not return any of my "Chrome devices for meetings" which are in a separate menu in the Admin console UI.

Answer (score 0):

Admin SDK Directory API does not work with Chrome for Meetings devices.

Comment: Is there another API that does?

Comment: Is this on the roadmap?

Comment: Not that I'm aware